# d3 mouseover event wont fire if I append svg to a div

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to get a simple mouseover to work on some rectangles in d3. If I append the SVG to "body" everything works just fine (first line of code). If I change the select to ".chart1" instead of "body" the mouseovers don't work. Has anyone seen this before?

```
var chart = d3.select(".chart1").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 50);

data = ["a", "b", "c",]

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var rect = chart.append("rect")
              .attr("x", 20*i)
              .attr("y", 10)
              .attr("width", 15)
              .attr("height", 15)

chart.selectAll('rect')
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("opacity", .5)
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("opacity", 1)
    });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jasonleehodges/um5f5ysv/

Comment: It does work: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/8s6nhxhz/

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need to use a for loop to append elements in a D3 code. That's not the idiomatic D3.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if mine has some type of collision in my stack but it's not working in my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jasonleehodges/um5f5ysv/

Comment: Again: the code in your snippet works. The code in your fiddle doesn't work because of pointer-events. There is absolutely no difference between appending the SVG to the body or to a div regarding this. I just voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not because you are appending svg to body or div with class `.chart1`

The problem of mouseover not working is in here.

```
var chart = d3.select(".chart1").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 50)
  //.style("pointer-events", "none");//WHY DISABLE MOUSE EVENT ON SVG
```

Fix would be to remove `.style("pointer-events", "none");`
and it will work on all the cases without any anomaly.

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v1jp954q/)

On another note you should not use a for loop, well that's not the d3 way(as put by @Gerardo Furtado).

so your code with `for`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var rect = chart.append("rect")
              .attr("x", 20*i)
              .attr("y", 10)
              .attr("width", 15)
              .attr("height", 15)
```

instead should be

```
var rect = chart.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d,i){return 20*i})
              .attr("y", 10)
              .attr("width", 15)
              .attr("height", 15)
              .attr("fill", "#cc004c")
              .attr("title","NBC")
              .attr("data-toggle","tooltip")
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/en8z9p33/)

Comment: I added that style line in an effort to try to resolve the problem. If I remove it from my fiddle it solves it for the fiddle but my production app is still not solved if I remove that line. If I change it to append to body it does work though. Not sure why there would be a difference between body and a div.

Comment: Definitely something to do with the style, in that case.
In the fiddle you provided I can see the problem with pointer-events.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was the style - the bootstrap row that was directly below the d3 object was moved 25px up and was covering the d3 (even though nothing was in that row) so it was likely hiding the d3 from mouseover events.